# Spatial segregation from a raster of racial distribution in the USA

Tags: qgis, python, raster, r, raster-calculator

I am trying to measure the degree of racial segregation at some geographic level (let's say the county level, for simplicity) in the USA. I have a shapefile with these geographic units.

To do so, I've downloaded [this map](http://demographics.coopercenter.org/DotMap/) in which there are dots of different colors (4 colors) and each color represents a different race. Each dot is a person. I have georeferenced the map so I have a properly georeferenced raster.

What would be the best way of computing a segregation index at the  level of my geographic units? Given that:

-In each pixel, there can be different colored dots, so that the resulting pixel is a mixture of colors. It is then not trivial for me to infer the % of each race in each pixel/grid
- I am not that familiar with research on spatial segregation, so I could use some help on the measure I have to choose.

I can do it using: QGIS, GDAL, Python or R

Comment: I believe that past literature has used entropy measures such as Shannon's.

Comment: You may want to take a look at ["Implementing Spatial Segregation Measures in R" by Hong et al 2014](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4240605/).

Comment: I think trying to infer the mix from blended colours is non-trivial.. probably easier to go to the [original data source](https://data2.nhgis.org/main)

Comment: Information on a person-by-person basis is hard to come by and not really accurate as people have an annoying tendency to move around a bit. I would only go to the census block level; census data should have the information on genealogy (make sure you include those that don't want to say).

Comment: Yes, I ended up going back to the data at the census track level.  Thanks for the comments. The map is beautiful though, would have been nice to exploit it